# Cygwin 32-bit Update on win 10 64-bit - Downloads Fail With Errors

Tags: download, cygwin, 32-bit

Trying to update my 32-bit Cygwin install on a Windows 10 64-bit fresh install and every setup-x86 I have tried fails with errors.
I had it all working on my old system, which was a Windows 7 upgrade to Windows 10. My 3rd party SDK with Cygwin plus an upgrade was installed a good few years ago while on Windows 7 then did the Windows 10 upgrade thing.   I could still compile my code for an embedded processor device with no errors after that.

But Microsoft corrupted my system with the last update (December 2022) so my system was unbootable and irreparable by any of their troubleshooting Advanced methods.
So I put a new hard drive in and installed windows 10 from scratch.
Two weeks later I have reinstalled much software but now I am at my SDK re-install and cannot get any Cygwin version to download.
I have a 3rd party SDK which instructs me to install their Cygwin first (version 1.5.18) then remove some environment variables, then go to http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html  and Follow the “Dead Simple Instructions" and go for "any version 2017 +".

After downloading the files I must copy the directory to my original install directory, thus upgrading the install.
I just cannot download anything though.

I went to that time machine page and was totally confused. I noticed they said "this is the last 32 bit install" on several places, so I tried clicking on all those setup-x86 links.
I tried running the downloaded setup-x86 files from the download directory but each one failed.
On most of the more recent setup-x86 files,(like 2.924)  it shows a small blue square telling me Windows protected me etc.  I click Run anyway and then it says "Cygwin is not supported on 32-bit windows".

So I tried earlier versions like 2.909 and they show the interface; I choose download, then choose the download directory ( a folder on my desktop) then I have tried both direct connection and use system proxy; then I select a mirror (tried all of them, I think) and it begins some action then stops with errors like:
"https:\cygwin.mirror.constant.com\x86\setup.ini line 12: The current ini file requires at least version 2.924 of setup.  Please download a newer version from [https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe"](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe%22)

But I have already tried 2.924 and it gives the "Cygwin is not supported on 32-bit windows" error!

With setup-x86-2.874.exe, it shows the interface etc. but in the mirror list all I see is http://update.setup.invalid.

With 2.774 it does the interface then "Unable to get setup.ini from 'my selected mirror url'.

Then I tried that page https://cygwin.com/install.html#unsupported, where I tried the circa urls and did these from an Administrator command line, as they say.      No good- errors.

Under "Dead Simple Instructions"(no they are not) I followed the link to the machine top level snapshot index, but each link their only gives a plain text list of files- nothing downloadable!

Anyway, copied a url link and then at step 4 it says click for setup-x86. So I did but that blue windows protection square appears. I say run anyway but then it says "Cygwin is not supported on 32-bit windows"!

I am at my wits end!  It all worked fine on my old system until Microsoft ruined it with their updates.
How can I get a newer cygwin update for my v1.5, s the 3rd party instructions say???

Comment: You will probably have to install the 64-bit version of cygwin. Download the latest setup.exe from cygwin.com for 64-bit. Install using that.

Comment: Unfortunately That won't work. The 3rd party software SDK explicitly says I must update their existing 32-bit install. They have had it that way for some years now. Their initial Cygwin install is 32-bit and they require a 32-bit update. It is then used to compile firmware for a small embedded processor.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone was looking for the solution, I found the answer in the [Cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2022-November/252542.html). You must launch the setup-x86.exe (setup-x86-2.924.exe) with the `--allow-unsupported-windows option --site circa_URL` arguments, much like the `-X` switch was used on prior legacy installers to disable signature checking. `circa_URL` here is a mirror of legacy repos for Cygwin, where http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2022/11/23/063457 is the suggested url in the mailing listing post.

Apparently, if you are on a true x86, non-64-bit, Windows OS, this flag is not necessary, though I think the repo mirror may be required.

Comment: I too needed to install 32bit Cygwin to run this particular program, and got the same nonsensical error message. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Aha!  I believe I have finally got this to work.
I just found a new release of the instructions for the 3rd party software SDK. They mention version 2.9.0 as the new version they are moving to.
I cannot access their download but I went back and read the Cygwin Time Machine page carefully again (http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html).
Under "Dead Simple Instructions", I looked through the list of dates and versions (http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/index.html) and found 2.9.0-1; surely close enough, eh?
So I copied the URL shown there.

Step 4 Run setup-x86.exe downloaded the setup file and Itried it from an Admin CMD prompt, adding the -X and -D switches. It failed with the 32 bit error, as before.

OK so I read again and near the bottom of the page I spotted "Cygwin Setup Archive".
Ah... I went to the link provided there (http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/setup/setup.html) and found setup-x86-2.901.exe.
After it downloaded, I again used the command prompt to run this and an interface appeared.
I was able to choose the existing install directory, the temporary download directory and add the URL I had copied earlier.
It proceeded to get the list of packages correctly.
I then selected to view files that were installed but may need updating and clicked Next.
It all went correctly.   Thanks to Doug who offered help already.
So there is a way to do this.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I would like to encourage you to contact the makers of your 3rd party SDK, and request that they provide a 64-bit solution.

Comment: Hi Doug, It seems they do now offer a 64-bit SDK but for another 5,000 or 6,000, because it's a different product, so I am not about to pay that!

Comment: Ouch. You may need to think about building a 32-bit Virtual Machine in the future.